# searchBar actions do not work with searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, searchbar

Im trying to configure searching bar in webview component.
my code looks:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
      [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    searchBar.text = @"";

}
```

but it's not working, searching dosen't work and keyboard is not hidding after cancel or click search. I had wired searchBar

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

and my seraching functions looks(i found this on web):

**SearchWebView.m**

```
@implementation UIWebView (SearchWebView)

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SearchWebView" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

    NSString *startSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

    NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"MyApp_SearchResultCount"];
    return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}

@end
```

**SearchWebView.h**
    @interface UIWebView (SearchWebView)

```
- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;

@end
```

and **SearchWebView.js**

```
// We're using a global variable to store the number of occurrences
var MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;

// helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes
function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
  if (element) {
    if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
      while (true) {
        var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
        var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

        if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
        span.appendChild(text);
        span.setAttribute("class","MyAppHighlight");
        span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        span.style.color="black";
        text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
        element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
        var next = element.nextSibling;
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
        element = text;
        MyApp_SearchResultCount++;  // update the counter
      }
    } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
      if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
        for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
  MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights();
  MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}

// helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
  if (element) {
    if (element.nodeType == 1) {
      if (element.getAttribute("class") == "MyAppHighlight") {
        var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        return true;
      } else {
        var normalize = false;
        for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          if (MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
            normalize = true;
          }
        }
        if (normalize) {
          element.normalize();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// the main entry point to remove the highlights
function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights() {
  MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
  MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your methods aren't firing I would guess your search bar delegate isn't set. Try putting this in your `viewDidLoad` method: `[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];`

You can also do this in Storyboard by clicking the search bar while holding control, and dragging to the ViewController.